# How to configure for windows Vscode for ARM toolchain with CMAKE

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, arm

Good afternoon,
I am trying to use the following configuration on Windows:

- VSCODE
- Arm tool chain
- CMake

And it looks like a nightmare to try to configure it.
I am failing up to now with the same error:
[main] Unable to determine what CMake generator to use. Please install or configure a preferred generator, or update settings.json, your Kit configuration or PATH variable. Error: No usable generator found

Is there any project template that i could use to go further?

I have the CMAKe extension installed on Vscode.
I have installed the windows version for the GNU Tool Arm Chain in C://Program Files (x86)//GNU Tools ARM Embedded//6 2017-q1-update//

I updated also the cmake-tools-kits.json by adding my compiler path:
[

{
"name": "gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q2-update",
"compilers": {
"C": "C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\6 2017-q1-update\bin\arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe",
"CXX": "C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\6 2017-q1-update\bin\arm-none-eabi-g++.exe"
},

In my CMakeLists.txt , i am not sure how to define  the CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE.

Should i define it with set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "C://Program Files (x86)//GNU Tools ARM Embedded//6 2017-q1-update//bin//arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe") ?

Comment: Did you look through CMake tutorial in the docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cmake-linux ?

Answer (score 1):

I would comment but I am not able due to reputation unfortunately.
If you 're looking for a quick solution, try the CMake gui which lets choose your generator. I had the same problem and this solved it fast. Before re-configuring in general I would also advise deleting the cache. The command line option -G will let you choose your Generator. Finally there is a way to do it through VSCode (if I am not mistaken) through File -> Preferences -> Settings -> (search for 'generator') and set the CMake generator.

Hope this helps.